# Toolbar won't display as action bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar

I'm currently trying to implement a `NavigationDrawer` within my application and have been following the Android Developer guide as to how this is implemented.

However, when trying to set a custom `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`, the `Toolbar` does not display within the application, almost as if the `setSupprtActionBar()` method does not do anything.

I think it is an issue with setting the themes as `.NoActionBar` somewhere incorrectly but I have tried changing them but have had no success.

**EDIT:** Following ʍѳђઽ૯ท's suggestions, here is the updated code which still does not show the toolbar.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Sets custom toolbar as default toolbar and imports menu icon
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Creates navigation drawer
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // set item as selected to persist highlight
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        // close drawer when item is tapped
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                        // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                        // For example, swap UI fragments here

                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            android:elevation="4dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/weather_mode_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:elevation="4dp"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_weather" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_mode_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/weather_mode"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_mode_desc"
                                android:layout_width="220dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/weather_mode_title"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/weather_mode_button"
                                android:text="@string/weather_mode_desc"
                                android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/weather_mode_button"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="@string/mode_button"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:elevation="4dp"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_wifi" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/wifi_mode"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_desc"
                                android:layout_width="220dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/wifi_mode_title"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/wifi_mode_button"
                                android:text="@string/wifi_mode_desc"
                                android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_button"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="@string/mode_button"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/temp_mode_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:elevation="4dp"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_temp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/temp_mode_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/temp_mode"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/temp_mode_desc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/temp_mode_title"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/temp_mode_button"
                                android:text="@string/temp_mode_desc"
                                android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/temp_mode_button"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="@string/mode_button"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

And here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Se the parent of `AppTheme.NoActionBar` to `AppTheme`.

Comment: Your layout needs to be rearranged, I advise you to follow some tutorial or something.

Comment: @murtadhaalsabbagh Thanks for the suggestion. This is my first ever app and was unsure of the best way to design the layout. I am aware of RecyclerViews but was unsure of how to implement them. If you have any suggestions for how the layout could be improved, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i assume it was the `FrameLayout` under the `Toolbar` and actually whole layout design. I have commented the important things about the design inside the comment block in layout codes.

In your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  
     ...
    </style>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity 
              android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In your *layout*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:title="MyToolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <!--<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />--> <!-- This shouldn't be here maybe under the NestedScrollView -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!-- Here your content -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="12dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_mode_card"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/weather_mode_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="weather_mode"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/weather_mode_desc"
                            android:layout_width="220dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/weather_mode_title"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/weather_mode_button"
                            android:text="weather_mode_desc"
                            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/weather_mode_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="mode_button" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_card"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="wifi_mode"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_desc"
                            android:layout_width="220dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/wifi_mode_title"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/wifi_mode_button"
                            android:text="wifi_mode_desc"
                            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_mode_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="mode_button" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/temp_mode_card"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/temp_mode_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="temp_mode"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/temp_mode_desc"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/temp_mode_title"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temp_mode_icon"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/temp_mode_button"
                            android:text="temp_mode_desc"
                            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/temp_mode_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="mode_button" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have implemented everything you have suggested but the toolbar is still not visible. Do you have any further suggestions? I have added the most recent code to the main post.

Comment: Yes. You can try using `CoordinatorLayout` and appbarlayout instead of `LinearLayout` and it’s because of `DrawerLayout` which can recognize Only `CoordinatorLayout` i suppose

Comment: Just to clarify, shall I replace the LinearLayout tags with android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and replace something else with appbarlayout?

Comment: @B.Stein Check the updated answer. Also, where did you need to use `FrameLayout`? As the content or sth? It could be replaced under the contents. Check the commented explanation inside the layout codes.

Comment: It worked brilliantly, thank you for your help. My only slight problem now is that the text in the toolbar is black/dark when I would like it white/light. If I set the toolbar theme to @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar, it cannot resolve it.

Comment: Try adding this to `AppBarLayout`: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your toolbar inside appbarlayout in xml and check .
Something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```